# What in detail is Format32bppPArgb

Tags: .net, performance, graphics, msdn

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx) says:

> Format32bppPArgb
>
> Specifies that the format is 32 bits per pixel; 8 bits each are used for the alpha, red, green, and blue components. The red, green, and blue components are premultiplied, according to the alpha component.

Does this mean that the RGB values are already multiplied and the A (Alpha) value is not used in real anymore? Does that mean if I have an PARGB `ImageFormat` used, it is not possible to see the real transparency anymore because the RGB values are already multiplied, or is it only a "nice done" function of GPU where user (developer) does not feel any difference in case of R/G/B result?

Regards

Answer (score 5):

The alpha values are retained in the pixel data and are available for use. But the pixel intensities are not the true value, but have been multiplied by the alpha.

The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premultiplied_alpha) has a good discussion of the pros and cons.

Comment: Hi David. You said the values are available. But then you said not true. On your link I found no P ARB article nor any discussions. Please advice.

Comment: Alpha values are true alpha. RGB values are multiplied. That link goes to a long section on pre-multiplied alpha. Don't know how you missed it.

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

> Some of the pixel formats contain premultiplied color values. Premultiplied means that the color values have already been multiplied by an alpha value.